# Как написать шаблон валидации url адреса с помощью REgexp

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Задача:

```
домен должен начинаться с http:// или https://;
затем www. — это необязательная группа;
IP-адрес — 255.255.255.255 или доменное имя — test.ru
порт — тоже необязательная группа. Порт начинается с двоеточия, за которым идут от 2 до 5 цифр.
путь — последовательность из цифр, / и латинских букв, на конце которого может стоять решётка #.
```

Как написать шаблон валидации url адреса с помощью REgexp?

Comment: а в чем вопрос собственно? какое задание?

Comment: Нужно написать шаблон для валидации url адреса с помощью Regexp

Answer (score 1):

Таких выражений очень много.

```
(?:http|https):\/\/((?:[\w-]+)(?:\.[\w-]+)+)(?:[\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?

[(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)

^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/vT2lF3/1

https://regexr.com/39nr7

https://www.regextester.com/94502

Надо пользоваться поиском.

Comment: “Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.”

Comment: Поэтому я привел аж три ссылки, все ресурсы очень популярны. А почему минус я так и не понял.

Comment: Еще раз прочтите комментарий пожалуйста. Зачем вы гоняете кого-то по ссылкам, вместо того чтобы сразу тут дать ответ? Минус, кстати, не мой

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @ВалерийМальцев поставьте, пожалуйста, что ответ дан.