# Как добавить запрет на ввод Русских букв в regex http/https

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть две регулярки для проверки `http/https` - ссылок. 
Они работают, но их нужно немного дорботать.

```
1 - ^(http|https|www)://.*$
2 - ^(ht{2}p|ht{2}ps|w{3})://.*$
```

Подскажите как мне добавить запрет на ввод русских букв в ссылку и запретить такой формат ссылки:
`https://://raw.githubusercontentвв.com` - Ссылка с доп `://` и Русские буквы `вв` их нужно запретить, как это сделать?

Comment: А как с китайскими буквами? Их того, тоже, запретить? :)

Comment: Попробуйте `^(?:ftp|http)s?://(?!.*://)(?!.*[А-ЯЁа-яё])[^/]+(?:/[^/]+)*/?$`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew А также с черточками (честно, забыл как они называются). Наличие русских букв в домене не означает что он невалидный, все зависит от того на каком этапе он преобразуется в punycode.

Comment: @ГеннадийП Диакритические занки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этими регулярками можно проверить только как раз то, что строка начинается на `http/https` и все. После `http/https` идет `//.*$`, где `.` это любой символ, поэтому и попадает любые последовательности, включая `://`.

В этом [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1120611/365777) я приводил несколько выражений для проверки URL. Может стоит взять одну из них за основу.

Небольшим примером проверки может служить следующее выражение

```
(http|https)://([a-zA-Z\d./])+
```

В `[]` перечислены все символы-алтернативы, которые могут встречаться, `+` означает, что такая последовательность должна быть минимум один раз

Comment: Спасибо, а как блокировать Русские буквы? Ваша регулярка не решает эту проблему, а вот со ```://``` помогло )

Comment: Русские буквы она не ищет, если они идут сразу за http

Comment: [Не нужно экранировать `/`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28http%7chttps%29%3a%2f%2f%28%5ba-zA-Z%5cd.%2f%5d%29%2b&i=https%3a%2f%2fraw.githubusercontent%d0%b2%d0%b2.com), они не являются специальными метасимволами регулярных выражений.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Для проверки на валидность URL можете воспользоваться [Uri.IsWellFormedUriString](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.uri.iswellformeduristring)

Например:

```
Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("https://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute)
> true
Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("https://://raw.githubusercontentвв.com", UriKind.Absolute)
> false
```